# Authorization via URL

Tags: php, email, authentication

I am building php web application. There is one actor who need access application with generated link to the page send with email message. Without user account. Can I develop authorization from such email link and do not require to enter any additional credentials?

**Pre-solution:**

I have auto-generated hash key for page stored in database, let's say:

> abc123abc

And the URL from user email message:

> `http://example.com?page=Hello&**auth=abc123abc**`

So when values match user can see page, otherwise not. Good enough.

**Problem**:

How can I prevent situation that **someone else** can use this link and login (user send it to a friend or saved as bookmark). I want only this user from email to login directly by clicking URL from his message. No other way. Is there any way to do it?

I would be thankful for any of your sugestions.

Answer (score 1):

The common solution for so called *one time links* is a similar one as you stated. You generate a secret key (for example a hash of something). You store this hash into your Database or somewhere else and connect that hash with basic information about what that key may be used for; like the ID of the user, a valid-until-date and the action that the user may execute with that hash.

Example:

```
|   Hash   | User_id |     ValidUntil      |  Action  |
| au3812j4 |   34    | 2015-11-19 23:52:50 | RESET_PW |
```

Then you send out a link that's providing that hash. (`http://somedomain/?hash=au3812j4)

When someone uses that link you check for the hash and if it exists you know the details for that hash (userid) and delete it from your database (so it's only one-time-usable).

You could prevent the user to give the link to someone else by storing some client information (e.g. IP-Adress) when the user gained that link (e.g. "password reset") and check that information when using the link but there's no good solution for that in my opinion.

Comment: Sugessiton appreciated. But you have mention "one-time-usable" link and there is a requirement to make it **any-time-usable**. User knows that he always can go to his email and open page from his link. Validating IP-Address would preclude user to open page e.g. from his mobile...

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent to use this link multiple times with changing the hash. If You don't want it You can put some cookie and store in Db an check it together to login. But it's not so secure.

Comment: Well, regenerate hash will need to send a new email. As I wrote in comment above, it would be brilliant to not sending more emails. Just one with one link. I start to suspect that I can achieve it simple way.

Answer (score 0):

For extra security you should make the token a 128 bit sequence generated from a CSPRNG.

On the server side store this using SHA-256. This prevents anyone gaining access to the hashes from using one of your links.

Link sent

```
http://example.com?page=Hello&auth=<hex of 128 bit token>
```

Server side:

```
Page         Original Token                     Single use token
Hello        hex(SHA-256(128 bit token))        hex(SHA-256(128 bit token))
```

Single use token is a new token you use which will be stored as a cookie. Once the user has visited this page, set the cookie and then hash it server side. This is a completely different token than the original.

For each visit, check the `Single use token` column. If there's something in it, ensure the browser is sending the cookie that matches the stored value when hashed. Therefore, anyone gaining access to the original link cannot use it without the cookie being sent.